# Can Bowser be permanently kept from permanently rampaging if I play right?

Tags: bowsers-fury

I'm finding hard to understand the exact thresholds for this, for some reason. Is it saying that, if I get 50 Cat Shines before the "continuous rampage" state is triggered, then I can avoid it all together? Or at least until I have all 100 Shines? Whichever's possible and longer?

> However, if the player collects more than 50 Cat Shines before the third battle, the continuous rampage state will not occur after it. The continuous rampage can also be skipped if the player lowers Fury Bowser's health to less than 50% of its full value through collecting Cat Shines. The damage from the lighthouses enables the player to defeat him during his fourth battle, which skips the rampage and begins the final chase sequence immediately.[3]

The above text is from the [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Fury_Bowser#Battle).

Comment: You probably can by getting the shines, but I'm not 100% sure, I have never tried it.